# How to print human readable format in KB, MB, GB instead of K, M, G?

Tags: bash

I have a widget on my desktop which shows the current size of the files in my 'Trash'. The code for the widget is the following:

```
du -ch ~/.Trash | grep total | cut -c 1-5
```

This will give me something like: '99M'. But I would like to display '99 MB' instead (and KB, GB respectively). Could you help me to replace the code with the right string to get this result (also notice the space between '99' and 'MB')? Thanks in advance!

PS: I use Mac OS X 10.11.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I find that, when the size is between 10 K and 99 K (say, for example, 42 K),
   the first five characters of the output are

   > `4`    `2`    `K`    (tab)    `/`

   (assuming that the pathname argument begins with `/` —
   which it will, if you’re specifying an argument that begins with `~`). 
   So that will be the output of `cut -c 1-5`: `42K     /`. 
   (I presume that `nnM` and `nnG`
   will have the same problem.) 
   It makes more sense to use `cut -f1` to get the first *field* of the output,
   rather than the first five characters.
2. What happens if you have a directory name that includes the word `total`? 
   Hint: It’ll get through the `grep`. 
   Rather than have `df` generate the data for every subdirectory,
   and then have `grep` throw it away,
   it makes more sense to have `df` generate only the total. 
   As [RomanPerekhrest points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/384377/23408#384381),
   you can do that by specifying the `-s` option.
3. As [dmgnx points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/384377/23408#384380),
   once you’ve got the number (ending with `K`, `M` or `G`),
   all you need to do is append the `B`. 
   So my composite solution is

   ```
   echo "$(du -sh ~/.Trash | cut -f1)B"
   ```
4. Oops!  I didn’t notice
   that you wanted to add a space between the number and the units. 
   OK, then you do need `sed` (or something similar):

   ```
   du -sh ~/.Trash | cut -f1 | sed 's/[KMG]$/ &B/'
   ```

   or perhaps just

   ```
   du -sh ~/.Trash | sed 's/^\([0-9.]*\)\([KMG]\).*$/\1 \2B/'
   ```

   (using `sed` to discard the directory name,
   and eliminating the `cut` altogether).

Answer (score 2):

Use `-s` (`--summarize`) option to display only a total size value:

```
du -sh | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)\([^B]\).*/\1 \2B/'
```

- `([0-9]*\)` - capturing total size value
- `([^B]\)` - capturing unit shortened value except `B` (bytes, which stays as is)

Comment: Maybe it's my fault, but if I enter `du -sh ~/.Trash | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)\([^B]\).*/\1 \2B/'` I get just ` B` as a result.

Comment: show `du -sh ~/.Trash` output at start

Comment: That gives me `87M /Users/philipp/.Trash`.

Comment: @PhilippL., try this also `du -sh | cut -f1 | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)\([^B]\)/\1 \2B/'`

Comment: That gives me: '  B87M'.

Comment: that poor macos, try `du -sh | sed 's/^\([[:digit:]]*\)\([^B]\).*/\1 \2B/'`

Answer (score 1):

You could clean the trailing whitespaces with tr and put the 'B' wrapping it in an echo command:

```
echo "$(du -ch ~ | grep total | cut -c 1-5 | tr -d '[:blank:]')B" | sed 's/\(K\|M\|G\)B/ \1B/'
```

Or just *sed* it :)

```
du -ch ~ | grep total | cut -c 1-5 | sed 's/\s\+$/B/' | sed 's/\(K\|M\|G\)B/ \1B/'
```

**edit 0:**
Didn't notice about space before unit, added last sed to do the job

Comment: The first one almost works, it gives me '87MB' (but not '87 MB').

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice about the space, I edited my answer to do the job ;)

Answer (score 0):

Brute forcibly:

```
du -ch ~/.Trash | grep total | cut -c 1-5 | 
  sed -e 's/K$/ KB/; s/M$/ MB/; s/G$/ GB/'
```